# Drag multiple images separately in swift

Tags: image, swiftui, foreach, offset, drag

I have just started coding and this is my first project, and I want to drag couple images set on the screen separately and leave them where they are dragged.
However currently I could manage dragging images separately but comes back in their original position... what should I change if I want to leave each images where they are dragged.

```
HStack {
    ForEach(stickers) { sticker in
        Image(sticker.name)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: self.screenWidth*0.2, height: self.screenWidth*0.2)
            .offset(x: self.selectedSticker == sticker ? self.dragOffset.width : 0,
                    y: self.selectedSticker == sticker ? self.dragOffset.height : 0)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .updating(self.$dragOffset, body: { (value, state, transaction) in
                        if nil == self.selectedSticker {
                            self.selectedSticker = sticker
                        }
                        state = value.translation
                        
                    }).onEnded { _ in self.selectedSticker = nil }
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is a common error. When you stop dragging, the translation goes back to zero, so your views go back to their origin. You need to set the offset amount in `.onEnded`. You didn't show an MRE, so I can't give you the exact code you need.

Comment: You can format your code using `ctrl-i` in Xcode, which will make it significantly more readable -- I've done that for you here. Also, you no longer need `self` when inside a struct like this -- that will clean things up, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that once the `sticker` is no longer the `selected.sticker`, its offset returns to zero. You'd need to set a variable that saves the images' locations after they are updated.

You could perhaps add another variable, `offset`, to `Sticker`:

```
struct Sticker: ... {
    var offset = CGSize.zero
    ...
}
```

And then store the offset value for each sticker in `sticker.offset` in `.onEnded`:

```
HStack {
    ForEach(stickers) { sticker in
        Image(sticker.name)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: self.screenWidth*0.2, height: self.screenWidth*0.2)
            .offset(x: self.selectedSticker == sticker ? self.dragOffset.width : sticker.offset.width,
                    y: self.selectedSticker == sticker ? self.dragOffset.height : sticker.offset.height)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .updating(self.$dragOffset, body: { (value, state, transaction) in
                        if nil == self.selectedSticker {
                            self.selectedSticker = sticker
                        }
                        state = value.translation
                    })
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        sticker.offset = dragOffset
                        self.selectedSticker = nil
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! it worked and answered to my question!!!